# Jsoup parse html page without change the content

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse an html page received through a proxy, so i have:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClient.execute(request);

InputStream stream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
String myHtml = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myHtml);
```

The issue is the html parsed and setted as a Document is totally different than the html received. i have a lot of div tag which are moved.

example :

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="header"> </div>
      <div id="content"> </div>
      <div id="footer"> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Become :

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="header"> </div>
      <div id="content"> </div>
    </div>


    <div id="footer"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The footer is moved out of the div parent.

I know Jsoup is based on W3C recommandations and i think the original html code is not valid but i need to keep the DOM unchanged.

I have tried to use the option Parser.xmlParser(), but still same results.

Anyone has an idea to avoid all changes made by Jsoup ? or another html parser to do the job ?

Comment: It's very hard to tell without seeing your input and output.

Comment: I will edit the post but imagine div moved in another place in the DOM or moved out of the div parent

Comment: What is `orginal`? Is it a string you read from a flie, some web connection?

Comment: @TDG this an httpResponse, i will edit this, thanks

Comment: Still not enough information. State the actual source url, so your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I though my example was explicite.. some div of my source or move in the DOM (like in my example) during the parse of Jsoup. I can't give you the url because this is not in production.

Comment: I guess that the html source might be invalid (missing a closing tag or something similar) and jsoup tries to clean it up (so jsoup works as intended, hence the question after the source). Try the source in a validator like https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: i did this already and as you can see, i say it in my post, the source is certainly invalid but i need to avoid this clean because of my incapacity to clean myself the source.

Comment: If sources are invalid, tools/libraries have two options: fix the source or throw an error/exception. So clean the source yourself (process the string), before parsing with jsoup or restructure in jsoup according to the intended structure.

Comment: I tried to restructure with jsoup but too much elements was moved and sometimes element with no id, class or name.. i can't clean the source.. There is no way to bypass the fix made by jsoup ? even in the throw ?